# Touch screen becomes sketchy when plugged in at a full charge?

Tags: charging, htc, htc-8x, screen, touch

I'm having a strange problem with my HTC 8x, specifically the touch screen. In the event that...

1. Phone is plugged into a charger
2. Battery is at full charge

Then the touch screen becomes barely responsive. Approximately only about 15-20% of what I do responds. I have to keep unplugging my phone to be able to use it.

Is there any known way to stop this from happening?

Comment: This could be probably because of the power source you connected or adapter you're using. I faced the same problem with Lumia that is not responsive to touch when I connected with Samsung's adapter.

Comment: Are you still using your original charger? If you replaced your charger with a generic one, or if you are using a charger from another brand, most likely this could be the cause. This can even happen with laptop touchpads when using generic chargers.

Comment: I had similar problems when charging a Lumia 920 with an HTC8x charger. The screen had ghost touch too. No fully charged.

Comment: The problem is with chargers which plug into the wall, at least I've narrowed it down to. I don't have this issue with computer plug-in. And the charger varies, but is not the one which came with the phone. Honestly I lost the charger which came with the phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is with the charger you're using. May be it's from manufactures other than your device's. It'll have different amperage and will affect your phone. You might not face any problems with charging via PC or laptop as it's current is lower as compared to normal wall chargers. Only I can say is, get a new generic charger asap.

Comment: The main one I use is one of those in-wall outlets with a USB charging port in it

Comment: May be you'll not face these problems with portable chargers.

Comment: Well that sucks, it's right at the head of my bed too so I use my phone when lying in bed

Comment: Better to get the amperage and voltage outputs of your generic charger and buy an in-wall outlets with equal or equivalent outputs.

Comment: Yeah this charger has 2 USB ports, port "A" is for all Apple products (which require higher rating) and port "B" is for "Everything else"