# Charging problems in Microsoft Lumia 535

Tags: lumia, keyboard, nokia-lumia-535, charging, touch

The problem is when I want to do some work while the *phone is on charging,* its goes crazy. I can't write a single letter normally when using keypad. It double/triple taps any word I press.

Means it becomes **very sensitive** in case of touch.

I cant scroll up/down the start screen normally. Is there any solution???

It dont creates any problem when say battery is charged upto 80% and above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Touch screen becomes sketchy when plugged in at a full charge?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2742/touch-screen-becomes-sketchy-when-plugged-in-at-a-full-charge)

Comment: thnx but My phone and charger is just 5 months old....and I always use the charger came with my phone. Should I change :(

Comment: Sounds like a fault with either the device or the charger - I'd suggest taking it back to the store, and have them test/fix/replace as appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friend, I also faced this issue on My Lumia 535. Please update you Mobile OS, These Touch issue fixed now. It is working good for me now.

Comment: My phone is already updated...8.1 and this charging problems occur sometimes....